# Size of 2D dict

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

What is an efficient way to find the size of a 2D dictionary? I'm currently using this oneliner:

```
sum((len(v) for v in d.itervalues()))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: That is the most efficient way possible, (note you don't need the extra brackets inside `sum(...)` eg. `sum(len(v) for v in d.itervalues())`. Are you actually looking for raw speed?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just thought that there could be some hidden properties of dictionaries I knew nothing about that would make my life easier, and my code more readable.

Comment: Just remove those extra brackets and that's as readable as you can get, I'm voting to close this as a *not real question* because you are not going to find any better way (which could be subjective as well ie. `from itertools import imap` `sum(imap(len, d.itervalues()))` is the other efficient/fast way but it's not considered more readable

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the 2D dictionary is a standard python dictionary where are the values are again python dictionaries there is no more efficient way than iterating over the values.

If a 2D dictionary is however defined as some instance of a class `Dict2D` that implements several of the special named methods, and whose values are not 'normal' `dicts`, but are some `dict` like classes that are smart enough to update the 'size' of their parent `Dict2D`, then you would just be able to do:

```
d2d = Dict2D()
# various assignments and updates ..
d2d['abc']['def'] = 1
d2d['ghi'] = {x = 4, y = 3}
d2d['abc'] = dict(klm=8, answer=42)
....
print d2d.size()
```

Whether it makes sense to implement such a `Dict2D` would depend on how transparent you want this to be and if you need to calculate the size often enough in between changes.

Comment: Subclassing seems a bit overkill in this case. It might come in handy for 'deeper' dicts though.